# How to calculate the product of a bunch of exponential functions in the fastest way possible?

Tags: fortran

This is Fortran code. I wanted to calculate a function called pYq_i, which is a product of mi exponential functions, see below,

[image]

The left hand side (LHS) is pYq_i, RHS is its expression. In the code, theta(1) is ki, theta(2) is Di. However ki and Di are random variables.
sigma, D, are just constants, and they can be any value. Yji is the value of the data, tj is the time. E.g., t1 - t5 are 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5.

Here is the code,

```
function pYq_i(theta,i)
integer(kind=i8) :: i,j
real(kind=r8) :: theta(dim_p),mean,sigma,pYq_i,fact_mean
fact_mean = D/theta(2)
pYq_i = normpdf_factor_pYq_i
do j = 1,mi
    mean = fact_mean*exp(-theta(1)*t(j))
    sigma = abs(sig*mean)   
    pYq_i = pYq_i/sigma*exp(-half*((Yji(j,i)-mean)/sigma)**2)   
enddo  
return
end function pYq_i
```

I want to calculate this pYq_i in the fastest way I can.

I was first thinking that I may do things like (not stict, just illustration here),

```
mean(:) = xxxxxxx
sigma(:) = xxxxxx
pYq(:) = 1.0/sigma(:)*exp(-half*((Yji(:,i)-mean(:))/sigma(:))**2)
pYq_i = product(pYq)
```

But the above code is slower than the do loop code. I guess in the do loop things care be kept in the cache or something.

So I did a trick, I rewrite the pYq_i expression in the do loop, such that now I calculate the log of the exponential, and sum them up, therefore I save some exp calculations in the loop. In the end I only need to do exp once. See the code below, pYq_i_detail is exactly the same as pYq_i,

```
function pYq_i_detail(theta,i) ! This should be faster than pYq_i.
integer(kind=i8) :: i,j
real(kind=r8) :: theta(dim_p),sigma_inv,pYq_i_detail,product_sigma_inv,log_pYq_i,fact_mean,xk
xk = theta(1)
fact_mean = theta(2)/D
log_pYq_i = zero
product_sigma_inv = normpdf_factor_pYq_i 
do j = 1,mi
    sigma_inv = sig_inv*fact_mean*exp(xk*t(j))
    log_pYq_i = log_pYq_i - (Yji(j,i)*sigma_inv-sig_inv)**2 
    product_sigma_inv = product_sigma_inv*sigma_inv
enddo
pYq_i_detail = abs(product_sigma_inv)*exp(half*log_pYq_i)   
return
end function pYq_i_detail
```

By the way, in all of the above code, if there is any variable not defined within the function, it is defined outside of the function. They are just variables, you can give them any value you want. Such as normpdf_factor_pYq_i, it is just something like 1/((2*pi)**mi). sig_inv is also just a constant.

The single calculation of it is cheap. However, the issue is that this function has to be evaluate many many many times in the code. Therefore the evaluation of this function seems to be a bottleneck and crucial.

Now I want to ask, does anyone has suggestions of an even faster version of calculating this pYq_i? Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about this function. Can you write the math down? There might be some nifty trick here possible.

Comment: There are a couple of things I notice but they will only have a small impact: (1) you can factor out `sig_inv` and use it only in the final computation. This removes some multiplications. it also seems that the use of `abs` is not needed at all. Furthermore, depending on the content of `xk` and `t(:)` we might do other stuff. Computing `product_sigma_inv` can be improved using `SUM` and a single `EXP` which will improve accuracy. and `log_pYq-i` could be computed using `DOT_PRODUCT` and a temporary vector. this will speed things up by caching.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example that could be used for benchmarking. Also, as @kvantour mentioned, the maths behind this function are essential - it could even be that using a function to calculate a single value could be a sub-optimal choice.

Comment: Is this a bottleneck in your code that you have determined from profiling?  If you know that `xk * t(j)` is always within the domain of `exp(x)` where only non-exceptional results are possible, it might be possible to modify the table-driven method of PKP tang for a fast `exp(x)`.

Comment: Thank you all! The math expression is added.

Comment: @kvantour Thank you for all of your suggestions man! Math is added. Yes I have tried sum and dot_product, but it seems slower than putting all these stuff just inside the do loop.

Comment: @steve Thank you! The single calculation of it is cheap. However, the issue is that this function has to be evaluate many many times in the code. Therefore the evaluation of this function seems to be a bottleneck. Tabulating of exp is indeed a good idea. Thing is that ki is a random variable and it is not very easy to evaluate its range. Because this is in the expectation maximization algorithm, ki is sampled from a gaussian whose mean and variance will change at each iteration.

Comment: Is your time always equidisatant? i.e. `t(i) = t(0) + i DeltaT`?

Comment: @kvantour No in general it is not. it is the time when taking a measurement on a patient for example. It may not be equidisatant.

Comment: May help: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/vector-mathematical-functions/vm-mathematical-functions.html#vm-mathematical-functions

Comment: Need to see a self-contained example.  We have no idea of the values for a number of variables, which may allow different levels of approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kvantour points out, since the exponent in the numerator is squared, you can replace the term `abs( D/Vi*exp(-ki*t(j)) )` with `D/Vi*exp(-ki*t(j))`. This allows this term to be factored out, giving a simpler exponent.

Then, replacing the product of exponentials with an exponential of a sum, and pulling as much out of the loop as possible, I get

```
function p(Yi,t,Vi,ki,D,sigma,mi)
  real(r8), intent(in) :: Yi(:)
  real(r8), intent(in) :: t(:)
  real(r8), intent(in) :: Vi
  real(r8), intent(in) :: ki
  real(r8), intent(in) :: D
  real(r8), intent(in) :: sigma
  integer,  intent(in) :: mi
  real(r8)             :: p
  
  real(r8) :: factor
  
  factor = D/Vi
  
  p = exp( -1/(2*sigma**2) * sum((Yi*exp(ki*t)/factor-1)**2) + ki*sum(t) ) &
  & / (sigma*abs(factor)*sqrt(2*pi))**mi
end function
```

I think this is as fast as you'll get with factorisation. To go faster you'll need to dive into optimisation, and to help with that we'll ideally need a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the typical use case.

Comment: thank you! Elegant solution! It speed is similar with my pYq_i_detail function. I guess this is almost the speed limit. Sometimes I feel that, sum(...) is slower than a loop of simple addition.

Comment: A further idea to speed this up (depending of the size of `t`) would be `norm2((Yi/factor)*exp(ki*t) -1)`  instead of `sum((...)**2)`. ... or use the BLAS alternative.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt good spot (although `norm2(x)` returns `sqrt(x.x)`, and unhelpully there isn't a unary intrinsic for `x.x`). Some BLAS / parallelisation would certainly help. I'm guessing computation time is dominated by calculating `exp(ki*t)` rather than the sums, but hard to know without the OP giving more information or profiling their code.